# How to open the jekyll serve in OS X El Capitan

Tags: ruby, github, web, jekyll

My computer is Macbook pro . the system is OS X El Capitan .

In the computer , I install ruby and jekyll , because I want to build a Github pages .

the jekyll's version is 3.1.2 , the ruby's version is 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162)

But I can not open jekyll .

you can see this:

```
weidu23u23deMBP:~ weidu23weidu23$ jekyll serve
Configuration file: none
            Source: /Users/weidu23weidu23
       Destination: /Users/weidu23weidu23/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
jekyll 3.1.2 | Error:  No such file or directory - /Users/weidu23weidu23/Library/Containers/com.ABabe.rarextractorfree/Data/Library/Preferences/com.ABabe.rarextractorfree.LSSharedFileList.plist
```

the Error is "no such file or directory ..." , but this file/directory is another application's file/directory , so I don't understand why?

Comment: rarextractorfree ? Smells like a virus. Sorry.